# Generating gnuplot eps files via script in php

Tags: php, dynamic, exec, gnuplot, eps

I asked a similar question a few days ago, but this is of a slightly different flavor; certainly more specific.

I have a php file that creates a gnuplot script dynamically, and then runs that script using 4 text files (1 per line of the plot) created beforehand with another php file.

The problem is that the graph.eps files are generated blank and I cannot figure it out. I have a feeling that it has something to do with the directory the text files are in.

This is the file I generate and then run.

```
set terminal postscript enhanced color
set size ratio 0.7058
set output '/srv/../A.2.5.1a.eps'
set grid

set key font "Arial,10"
set key center bot
set key out vertical
set key horizontal center
set key box

set style line 1  linetype 1 linecolor rgb "red"  linewidth 2.000 pointtype 6 pointsize     default
set style line 3  linetype 1 linecolor rgb "#DAA520"  linewidth 2.000 pointtype 6 pointsize default
set style line 4  linetype 1 linecolor rgb "#006400"  linewidth 2.000 pointtype 6 pointsize default
set style line 6  linetype 1 linecolor rgb "blue"  linewidth 2.000 pointtype 6 pointsize default

set multiplot
set palette model RGB functions 0.8+gray/3, 0.8+gray/3, 0.8+gray/3
set pm3d map
set isosample 100,100

unset colorbox
unset border
unset xtics
unset ytics
set nokey
set nolabel
set size 1.025,1.2
set origin -0.021,-0.06

splot y t ' '

set title "SECTION A.2.5.1a TEST RESULTS"
set key box
set key horizontal center bot
set y2tics 0 , 200
set ytics nomirror
set xtics nomirror

set border
set xtics 250
set xtics font "Arial,8"
set ytics 1750
set size 1,1
set xtics out offset -1,-0.5
set xtics rotate by 45

unset origin
unset x2tics

set xlabel "Loop Length, 26AWG(kft)"
set ylabel "Downstream Data Rate (kbps)"
set y2label "Upstream Data Rate (kbps)"
set xrange [ 250 : 5500 ] noreverse nowriteback
set yrange [ 0 : 14000 ] noreverse nowriteback
set y2range[ 0 : 1400 ] noreverse nowriteback
set bmargin  7

plot    "DSE_A.2.5.1a.txt"  ls 4 title 'Expected Downstream Rate' with linespoints,      \
"DS_A.2.5.1a.txt" ls 1 title 'Measured Downstream Rate' with linespoints, \
\
"USE_A.2.5.1a.txt"  axes x1y2 ls 6 title 'Expected Upstream Rate' with linespoints, \
"US_A.2.5.1a.txt"  axes x1y2 ls 3 title 'Measured Upstream Rate' with linespoints

unset multiplot
```

Once this is created, I use:

```
exec( "{$pathName} gnuplot {$File}");
```

The $pathName is the CWD for the file and the $File variable explains itself.

I've tried using plot $pathname/DS_A.2.5.1a.txt, etc but that doesn't work either.

Thanks for your time and I apologize about the lengthy post. I changed the set output path because it was very long and contains relatively private information.

Thanks and I look forward to all responses!

Edit: I just read http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/487/plot-your-graphs-with-command-line-gnuplot/ and I think that maybe not chmod-ing and that other command might be a problem, but when I try that it still doesn't work.

Since it's being run remotely on a server I do not get the error messages that I do when I manually run gnuplot.

Comment: If this blank output is only occurring with the eps-terminal and not for the x11 or pdfcairo terminal, then you found the problem. If that is not the case, try debugging it by instead of using data files as input to the plots use functions like x or 2*x. If I run your script with pseudo functions instead of the data files I do not get a blank output.

Comment: I would be able to debug this fine myself, except that I do not have write privs on the server that this script is running on, so I cannot actually try it manually. The script is run on the server through an administrator account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be instructive to display the executed command. Instead of:

```
exec( "{$pathName} gnuplot {$File}");
```

try

```
$command_to_execute = "$pathName gnuplot $File";
echo $command_to_execute . "\n";
exec( $command_to_execute );
```

It appears that your path to `gnuplot` is invalid. You may need to remove the space, like this:

```
$command_to_execute = "{$pathName}gnuplot {$File}";
```

and you may need to add a slash, like this:

```
$command_to_execute = "{$pathName}/gnuplot {$File}";
```

Comment: I will try that, but I have switched to
    exec( "gnuplot {$pathName}/{$File}" );

and that doesn't work, either

Comment: You should specify the full path to gnuplot, and ensure that the webserver user has permissions to execute it.